# URL development and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

My site is made-up of the main page, and multiple sub-directories, all under the same domain.

My URLS are currently like .................| Ideal clean version:

---

- **`mysite.com`**

  - `mysite.com/?content=content1` ......................| `mysite.com/content1/`
  - `mysite.com/?content=content2&page=4` ........| `mysite.com/content2/4/`
  - `mysite.com/?content=content3` ......................| `mysite.com/content3/`
  - `mysite.com/?content=content4` ......................| `mysite.com/content4/`
  - `mysite.com/?content=article&id=34` ............| `mysite.com/article/34/`

---

Then the sub-directories are essentially the same:

- **`mysite.com/subdir`**, **`mysite.com/subdir2`**, **`mysite.com/subdir3`**, etc

  - `mysite.com/subdir/?content=content1` ...................| `mysite.com/subdir/content1/`
  - `mysite.com/subdir/?content=content2&page=4` .....| `mysite.com/subdir/content2/4/`
  - `mysite.com/subdir/?content=content3` ...................| `mysite.com/subdir/content3/`
  - `mysite.com/subdir/?content=content4` ...................| `mysite.com/subdir/content4/`
  - `mysite.com/subdir/?content=article&id=34` .........| `mysite.com/subdir/article/34/`

---

I've used mod_rewrite briefly, but I'm not sure how to approach these multiple variables. Also, how would I differentiate between the actually subfolders, and the content variable. As so to prevent 'subdir' or 'subdir2' from being plugged in as the content variable for the root site.

I've played around with plenty of code snippets, but I've wiped my .htaccess *slate* clean, and approach you all in an attempt to help me repopulate it. Your input would thoroughly be appreciated.

---

**Note:**
The only time the page query string will be needed is when 'content' == 'content2'

`?content=content2&page=4`

**Same rule is shared by the article/id relationship, all other 'content' values are expected to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replicate something like that in the main and subdirectories:

```
RewriteRule  ^(content\d+)(?:/(\d+))?/?$  ?content=$1&page=$2
```

Or you could split it up into two distinct RewriteRules, if you don't want an empty &page= param.

```
RewriteRule  ^(content\d+)/?$             ?content=$1
RewriteRule  ^(content\d+)/(\d+)/?$       ?content=$1&page=$2
```

Same for approach for `article`.

Answer (score 0):

Will work for you.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /?content=$1 [L,QSL] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /?content=$1&page=$2 [L,QSL] 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/id/([^/]*)/$ /?content=$1&id=$2 [L,QSL]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried copying that into my .htaccess and I get an `Internal Server Error`. I tried removing various lines, and sections, but the page won't load unless I remove all of your code.